# (discord js antispam) How do I make a whitelist channel command?

Tags: discord.js, spam-prevention

I just made my bot public, and I would like to know how to make a channel whitelist command so the antispam ignores a spam channel. If any of you are wondering, it is based on the Pufferfish Eating a Carrot meme. This is my antispam code:

````
const antiSpam = new AntiSpam({
    warnThreshold: 10, // Amount of messages sent in a row that will cause a warning.
    kickThreshold: 20, // Amount of messages sent in a row that will cause a ban.
    banThreshold: 30, // Amount of messages sent in a row that will cause a ban.
    maxInterval: 6000, // Amount of time (in milliseconds) in which messages are considered spam.
    warnMessage: '{@user}, Please stop spamming.', // Message that will be sent in chat upon warning a user.
    kickMessage: ':carrot: **{user_tag}** has been aeughed for spamming :carrot:', // Message that will be sent in chat upon kicking a user.
    banMessage: ':knife: **{user_tag}** has been chopped for spamming :knife:', // Message that will be sent in chat upon banning a user.
    maxDuplicatesWarning: 10, // Amount of duplicate messages that trigger a warning.
    maxDuplicatesKick: 20, // Amount of duplicate messages that trigger a warning.
    maxDuplicatesBan: 30, // Amount of duplicate messages that trigger a warning.
    exemptPermissions: [ 'ADMINISTRATOR'], // Bypass users with any of these permissions.
    ignoreBots: true, // Ignore bot messages.
    verbose: true, // Extended Logs from module.
    ignoredUsers: [], // Array of User IDs that get ignored
    ignoredChannels: ['channels to be whitelisted'] // Array of string channels IDs that are ignored.
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

• First enable the [developer mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slbgk.png)

• Now right click on any channel and click [copy id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhuiO.png)

so add your channel ids in the array

```
ignoredChannels: ["1234567890", "1234567890","1234567890"]
```

you can also use quick db to store those id

```
 const db = require('quick.db')
 db.push('<server_id>.channels', "channel_id")
```

now, after that
put anti-spam variable below quick.db variable

replace ignoredChannels with

```
ignoredChannels: db.get('<server_id>.channels')
```